# showing message after email generation or sending through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
 function registration_ajax(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|is_unique[register.email]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data = '{"status":"false","message":"Email already exists"}';
        }
        else
        {

            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $data= array(
                'email'=>$email  
            );

            $last_id = $this->model->registeration($data);            
            if ($last_id>0) {
                $this->send_email($email);
                $data = '{"status":"true","message":"Email Created successfully"}';
            }

        }
        echo $data;
    }

    public function send_email($to='',$username="",$from='khadija@precisetech.com.pk')
        ///function send_mail()
    {

        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $toEmail = $this->encrypt->encode($to);

        $toEmail = str_replace('/','forwardSlash',$toEmail);
        $toEmail = str_replace('=','equalSign',$toEmail);
        $toEmail = str_replace('+', 'plusSign', $toEmail);

        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
                $config['smtp_host']    = 'sadasds';//pust mail.com.pk
                $config['smtp_port']    = '25334';
                $config['smtp_user']    = 'example';
                $config['smtp_pass']    = 'example1';   
                $config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
                $config['mailtype']     = 'html';
                $config['validation'] = FALSE; // bool whether to validate email or not          

                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $message = '<h1 align="center">Hellow</h1>';
                $message = '<html><body style="color:#000; font-weight:normal; font-size:13/14px;"><p style="color:#000;">Hi!</p>';
                $message .= '<table rules="all">';

                $message .= "<p>Congratulations! You have almost completed your registration on Electronic Mall.<br><br>Click on link  here to confirm your email address<br> <a href=\"http://10.10.10.44/Freeclassified/index.php/controller/register_second/$toEmail\">10.10.10.44</a><br><br>Thank you for joining us and becoming part of world's largest local classified sites.In our website, you can enjoy simple ad posting, easy searching and endless local listing for products.We appreciate you for choosing us in online market place.<br> Wishing you alot of success on your classified journey.Get started now!<br><br></p>";
                $message .= "<p>Regards,<br>The Electronic Mall Team</p>";

                $message .= "</table>";
                $message .= "</body></html>";
                $this->email->from($from);
                $this->email->to($to);
                $this->email->subject('Confirmation Email');
                $this->email->message($message);
                if(!$this->email->send()){
                    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                    die();
                }else{

                }


            }


////ajx code
//////////////////


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registration_form').on('submit',function(e){
      var email = $('#email').val();

      $.ajax({

         url: "<?=base_url('controller/registration_ajax')?>",
         // url: "<?=base_url('controller/register')?>",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(res){
          var data = $.parseJSON(res);
          var status = data.status;
          var message = data.message;
          if(status == 'true'){
           /// $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('#message_sent').html(message);
          }
          else{
            $('#message').html(message);
          }
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

I want that after email is sent successfully then this message should be displayed

```
$data = '{"status":"true","message":"Email Created successfully"}';
```

When I commented the mail sending function then it display the successful message, I want that the message should be display after sending email.

Comment: O mery bhai yahan par apnay personal password mat deya karo, Question main sy remove kero apna email ka password!

Comment: thank you @tashreef for sharing password... ab tashreef rkh k betho... kindly edit it

Comment: thanx for remind me this.

Comment: suggest change your password and be careful on pasting the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried returning a value from your send_email function?

```
if(!$this->email->send()){

    return 'success';
}else{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'To complete registration, click the link in email we just send you at khadija@precisetech.com.pk');
   redirect('controller/login_register','refresh');

   die();
```

}

then in your :

```
if ($last_id>0) {
   $res = $this->send_email($email);
   if($res === 'success'){
      $data = '{"status":"true","message":"Email Created successfully"}';
   }

}
```

Comment: No I want if email generated then it show me success message but message is sended and it don't give me message of success. I don't want to return any value.

Comment: @tashreef the return value is actually the success response.

Comment: Dear I am showing this success message in pupop model and also insert mail from popup model. how  no response in  poup model  $data = '{"status":"true","message":"Email Created successfully"}';
   }. error message is correct but no success message after email sending when I comment the email function then it show success message that's why. then insert record in database but no email is generated.

Comment: When the message is successfully sent, do it insert the record in database?